# How would you count every occurrence of a term in all files in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, grep

How would you count every occurrence of a term in all files in the current directory? - and subdirectories(?)

I've read that to do this you would use `grep`; what is the exact command?

Also, is it possible to the above with some other command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `grep` + `wc` (this will cater for multiple occurences of the term on the same line):

```
grep -rFo foo | wc -l
```

- `-r` in `grep`: searches recursively in the current directory hierarchy;
- `-F` in `grep`: matches against a fixed string instead of against a pattern;
- `-o` in `grep`: prints only matches;
- `-l` in `wc`: prints the count of the lines;

```
% tree                 
.
├── dir
│   └── file2
└── file1

1 directory, 2 files
% cat file1 
line1 foo foo
line2 foo
line3 foo
% cat dir/file2 
line1 foo foo
line2 foo
line3 foo
% grep -rFo foo | wc -l
8
```

Comment: I think the nicest one.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks! I like yours too (and upvoted it already)

Comment: I think `PCREs` shouldnt be used since they are experimental

Comment: PCREs aren't "experimental", but they're also not always compiled in to grep (which is why I use pcregrep when I need them).  In this case, they're unnecessary, though, since the question asks about a "term" which is likely a fixed string, not a pattern of any kind.  So, `-F` would probably be faster.

Comment: @dannysauer I used PCREs because for some (wrong) reason I thought they were *needed* to match multiple occurences on the same line, but indeed they're not. I just didn't try using `-F` instead of `-P`. Thanks for the great suggestion, updating using `-F`, which indeed fits better here.

Answer (score 9):

`grep -Rc [term] *` will do that. The `-R` flag means you want to recursively search the current directory and all of its subdirectories. The `*` is a file selector meaning: all files. The `-c` flag makes `grep` output only the number of occurrences. However, if the word occurs multiple times on a single line, it is counted only once.

From `man grep`:

```
  -r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.
          This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively.  Follow all symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

If you have no symbolic links in your directory, there is no difference.

Comment: you can add the `-c` flag to `grep`. Then grep counts itself and you don't need the`wc`

Comment: you might wanna put `--` before `*`

Comment: The `*` will only expand to non-dotfiles, so you miss all those.  It makes more sense to just use "." since your'e going to process arguments recursively anyway - and that will get dot files.  The bigger problem here is that this will could the number of lines, not the number of occurrences of a word.  If the term appears multiple times on one line, it will only be counted once by "grep -c"

Answer (score 2):

In a small python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

s = sys.argv[1]
n = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        f = root+"/"+f      
        try:
            n = n + open(f).read().count(s)
        except:
            pass
print(n)
```

- Save it as `count_string.py`.
- Run it *from the directory* with the command:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/count_string.py <term>
  ```

#### Notes

- If the term includes spaces, use quotes.
- It counts every occurence of the term recursively, also if multiple occurences in one line.

#### Explanation:

```py
# get the current working directory
currdir = os.getcwd()
# get the term as argument
s = sys.argv[1]
# count occurrences, set start to 0 
n = 0
# use os.walk() to read recursively
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currdir):
    for f in files:
        # join the path(s) above the file and the file itself
        f = root+"/"+f
        # try to read the file (will fail if the file is unreadable for some reason)
        try:
            # add the number of found occurrences of <term> in the file
            n = n + open(f).read().count(s)
        except:
            pass
print(n)
```

Comment: The python guy **;)** +1

Comment: btw what's the `root` and `f` for?

Comment: `root` is the path to the file including "above" the current directory, `f` is the file. Alternatively,  `os.path.join()` could be used, but is more verbose.

Comment: And `n = n + open(f).read().count(s)`?

Comment: This appears to be the only answer which counts *all occurrences* of the term as the OP requested. AFAIK, all the solutions using grep will count all the lines on which the term occurs, so a line which includes the term three times will only count as one occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

As a variant of @kos's nice answer, if you are interested in itemizing the counts, you can use grep's `-c` switch to count occurrences:

```
$ grep -rFoc foo
file1:3
dir/file2:3
```